# hibernate not doing a eager fetch (using fetch="join" and lazy="false")

Tags: java, mysql, performance, hibernate, fetch

I want to do a eager fetch in my webapplication.I have following in my mapping file

```
<many-to-one name="user" class="com.xyz.beans.User" lazy="false" fetch="join">
    <column name="startedBy" />
</many-to-one>
<many-to-one name="participantByParticipant1" class="com.xyz.beans.Participant" lazy="false" fetch="join" cascade="all" >
    <column name="participant1" />
</many-to-one>
<many-to-one name="participantByParticipant2" class="com.xyz.beans.Participant" lazy="false" fetch="join" cascade="all">
    <column name="participant2" />
</many-to-one>
```

I have a query as follows

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Post as p order by challenge.createdOn desc");
query.setFirstResult(0);
query.setMaxResults(10);
```

Participand table has has some mapping to other tables.And their fetch strategy is same
This takes around 2+ seconds to execute above query and i can see following queries generated by hibernate
1 select query to fetch 10 post
20 select queries for participant tabel (as there are 2 participants per post)

1) Why so? Why is it not taking a single join?
2) How can i optimize this ?Its taking too much time.The table only as 10 records now

Comment: "*I want to fetch everything eagerly in my webapplication.*". Why do you need to fetch everything eagerly? Also, there is nothing wrong with XML mappings though nowadays a trend is to use annotations rather than XML mappings. It simplifies DAO a lot.

Comment: As i need to display it on UI.The above query take around 2 seconds and thats too much. i want to fech all related tables in one selct statement in one go

Comment: You can do the same with `FetchType.LAZY`, if you use a filter named [`org.springframework.orm.hibernateX.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html). It allows for lazy loading in web views(UI as you say).

Comment: But i do not want to use lazy loading.I want to use eager loading.Why is hibernate not doing that when i specify lazy ="false" explicitly?Lazy loading is causing perfomance problem.It is taking 2+ seconds for the above mentioned simple query which is every bad

Comment: Eager loading tends to significant amount of performance bottleneck, especially when your entity has many child rows, 10000 or so. Loading them everytime when the parent entity is loaded even though they are not required is somewhat completely unnecessary. What do you think?

Comment: I agree.But my parent entity has only 1 child as Participant1 and and  one child as Participant2 .It is many to one mapping .

Answer (score 0):

Setting `lazy="false" fetch="join"` in your mapping has an effect only when you directly get your Entity:

```
session.get(Post.class, postId);
```

When you do a query, you explicitly need to declare your fetch strategy. Otherwise it will still be lazy:

```
from Post as p left join fetch p.user
```

As usual, there are many variations and exceptions to this rule. You may find more in Hibernate docs, [16.3. Associations and joins](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-joins).